# how to solve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to call api from a node function.

It is returning

(node:19396) Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
(node:19396) Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:19396) [DEP0018] Deprecation Warning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Using axios. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're hitting an `https://` endpoint which is using self-signed certificate (not verified using any CA). `axios` is doing the certificate validation and failing with the same error.

If you don't really care much about certificate validation and trust, you can choose to ignore it:

```
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false
})

axios.get(url, { httpsAgent })
```

Else you can specify the crt and key files inside the httpAgent like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/crt/file'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/pem/file'),
  passphrase: "my_pass"
})
```